# How to get real frame in UIImageView that hold in parent UIView after pinch in/out or rotation

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIView that hold a UIImageView , and I need after pinch in/out or rotation the UIImageView to get the image that show in the parrent UIview.

the parent UIview with clipsToBounds = YES.

this is the UIImageView in the UIview before any touching :

[image]

this is the image after pinch in  :

[image]

how I get the Right frame that I see in UIView from the original image ?

this is my GestureDetected :

```
 - (void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 {
UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGFloat scale = [recognizer scale];
    [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, scale, scale)];
    [recognizer setScale:1.0];
}
}

- (void)rotationGestureDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGFloat rotation = [recognizer rotation];
    [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, rotation)];
    [recognizer setRotation:0];
}
}

- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)];
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
}
 }
```